# how to use Contains to select specific datas using EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I need to make a list with conditions with many relatioships and works fine for me, but now I want to list for a specific row of my DataBase, I'm trying to use `Contains` but it doesn't work for me, so far i got this :

```
var query = context.anuncio.Where(w =>
                       w.usuarios.cidade.nome_cidade == search.Cidade
                    && w.usuarios.regiao.nome_regiao == search.Regiao
                    && w.usuarios.cidade.estado.nome_estado == search.Estado
                    && w.usuarios.cidade.estado.pais.nome_pais == search.Pais
                    && w.categoria_mestre.nome_categoria_mestre == search.CategoriaMestre
                    && w.categoria.nome_categoria == search.Categoria
                    && search.Pesquisa.Contains(w.titulo_anuncio)
                    && w.sub_categoria.nome_sub_categoria == search.SubCategoria).
                    Select(a => new {.....
```

I'm trying to select items who matches with my custom search.

The `search` object only defined string properties:

```
public class Search
{
    public string Pais { get { return "Brasil"; }  }
    public string Regiao { get; set; }
    public string Cidade { get; set; }
    public string Estado { get; set; }
    public string CategoriaMestre { get; set; }
    public string Categoria { get; set; }
    public string SubCategoria { get; set; }
    public string Pesquisa { get; set; }


}
```

Values that I'm passing to query :

```
"Regiao":"GRANDE RECIFE",
"Cidade":"Jaboatão dos Guararapes",
"Estado":"PERNAMBUCO",
"CategoriaMestre":"",
"Categoria":"",
"SubCategoria":"",
"Pesquisa":"Iphone"
```

Values that are recorded in DataBase :

When I make a query with a static values in `nome_regiao`,`nome_cidade`,`nome_pais`,`nome_estado` i have this values!

```
"id_anuncio": 4,
"titulo_anuncio": "Vendo Iphone 5s ",
"descricao_anuncio": "Iphone 5s novo desbloqueado",
"imagem1": "2",
"valor_produto": 2500,
"data_publicacao": "2016-10-09T12:36:38.193",
"nome_usuario": "Nathiel Barros",
"num_celular": "8188812011",
"CEP": "54315310",
"nome_regiao": "GRANDE RECIFE",
"nome_cidade": "Jaboatão dos Guararapes",
"nome_estado": "PERNAMBUCO",
"nome_pais": "BRASIL",
"tipo_produto": "NOVO",
"id_usuario": 1
```

And I want to list everything that has to do with the "iphone" word inside of `titulo_anuncio`

Comment: `search` cannot be typeof `string` if it contains properties such as `Cidade`,`Regiao` etc. Show your models.

Comment: What is the error message when you say it don't work for you?

Comment: @CodeNotFound I don't have any return!

Comment: Since `search.Pesquisa` is `string`, why are you not just using `&& w.titulo_anuncio== search.Pesquisa` (or are you wanting to filter results where the value of `titulo_anuncio` contains some characters in `Pesquisa`?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Exactly! I want to search of all table everything that has "SearchName" by the title. let's say that `titulo_anuncio` is "APPLE IPHONE 6S" and when i fill the search prop i want to retrieve anything with iphone search inside of `titulo_anuncio`

Comment: Still not clear. If the value of `Pesquisa` is "APPLE IPHONE 6S" and you have a record where `titulo_anuncio` is "APPLE IPHONE 6S" then you just need a `==` (but you have multiple `&&` conditions which means you will only find a match if every condition matches

Comment: @StephenMuecke can we chat? I think I could  explain better there.

Comment: It would be best if you show the values of the properties in `search` that your passing to the query, and the values of the table row that you expect to return

Comment: @StephenMuecke I think now has more details!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125300/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-nathiel-paulino).

Answer (score 0):

```
// Contains linq

     var query = context.anuncio.Where(w =>
                   w.usuarios.cidade.nome_cidade.Contains(search.Cidade)
                && w.usuarios.regiao.nome_regiao.Contains( search.Regiao)
          )
```

Comment: Please explain your answer